# Does removing CMOS battery clear CMOS?

Tags: motherboard, battery, cmos, supermicro

I thought CMOS battery kept CMOS memories alive. In light of this, I find this section of my SuperMicro motherboard's manual puzzling:

[image]

Why remove the battery and then short some connections? Wouldn't just removing the battery do the job?

Comment: "Why remove the battery and then short some connections? Wouldn't just removing the battery do the job?" because the battery will keep current cmos unless you do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because mother boards usually have a few capacitors. They will store electricty to keep the CMOS data. Short the jumper will discharge the capacitors. If you remove the battery, and wait a long time, the capacitors are also discharged and CMOS cleared.